# Laravel 5: Route model binding in a group

Tags: laravel, binding, model, routes

I made a Route model binding in the `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);

        $router->model('article', 'App\Article');
    }
```

My route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'articles'], function(){
  //some routes ....

  Route::group(['prefix' => '{article}'], function(){
    Route::get('', [
      'as' => 'article.show',
      'uses' => 'ArticlesController@show'
    ]);

    Route::get('comments', [
       'as' => 'article.comments',
       'uses' => 'ArticlesController@comments'
    ]);
  });
});
```

`/articles/666` works perfectly

`/articles/666/comments` show me Http not found exception.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate this issue but only when I did not have an article with id of 666 in the database.

Strangely enough, I didn't come across that issue when I did not have my route binding setup.

Try creating an article with id of 666 or changing the id to an article you do have and it should work.  If it does not, you may have another route overriding this one.  Run the command `php artisan route:list` to get a list of all your routes.  If you are caching routes, be sure to regenerate the cache as well.

Comment: I don't really see why? OP has the article binding in the group prefix already, and says `/articles/666` works fine.

Comment: the 666 is just an example, it maybe another id, still not working

Comment: That's strange, the code you've shown is working perfectly for me (as long as I have an article with the id I try in the database).  The issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Using your routing you can inject the model directly into the action:

```
// ArticlesController.php
...
public function show(Article $article) {
    return response()->json($article);
}
```

But bear in mind that you need to use the 'bindings' middleware group to ensure that the model gets implicitly from the route.
So eg in your routes config:

```
Route::middleware('bindings')->group(function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'articles'], function(){
        Route::group(['prefix' => '{article}'], function(){
            Route::get('', [
                'as' => 'article.show',
                'uses' => 'ArticlesController@show'
            ]);

            Route::get('comments', [
                'as' => 'article.comments',
                'uses' => 'ArticlesController@comments'
            ]);
        });
    });
});
```

This is not something that appears well documented.