# Route Model Binding does not work on route group in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Suppose I have these routes :

```
$api->group(['prefix' => 'Course'], function ($api) {
    $api->group(['prefix' => '/{course}'], function ($api) {
       $api->post('/', ['uses' => 'CourseController@course_details']);
       $api->post('Register', ['uses' => 'CourseController@course_register']);
       $api->post('Lessons', ['uses' => 'CourseController@course_lessons']);
     });
});
```

As you can see all `/` , `Register` and `Lessons` route prefixed by a `course` required parameter.

`course` parameter is a ID of a `Course` model that I want to use for route model binding.

But In the other hand when I want use `course` parameter for example in  `course_details` function, it returns `null`. like this :

```
    public function course_details (\App\Course $course)
    {
        dd($course);
    }
```

But if I use below, all things worked fine :

```
    public function course_details ($course)
    {
        $course =   Course::findOrFail($course);

        return $course;
    }
```

Seems that it can not bind model properly.

What is Problem ?

**Update :**

In fact I'm using [dingo-api](https://github.com/dingo/api) laravel package to create an API. all routes defined based it's configuration.

But there is an issue about route model binding where to support route model binding we must to add a middleware named `binding` to each route that need model binding. [HERE](https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/1179#issuecomment-243965337) is described it.

A bigger problem that exists is when I want to add `binding` middleware to a route group, it does not work and I must add it to each of routes.

In this case I do not know how can I solve the problem.

**Solution:**

After many Googling I found that :

I found that must to add `bindings` middleware in the same route group that added `auth.api` middleware instead adding it to each sub routes separately.
means like this :

```
$api->group(['middleware' => 'api.auth|bindings'], function ($api) {
});
```

Answer (score 5):

add in kernel.php

```
 use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
             ...
            'bindings' => SubstituteBindings::class,
        ];
```

and in your group route:

```
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'bindings'])->group(function(){
    ... you routes here ...
    });
```

this worked for me. thanks

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you so much. Saved a lot of my time.

Comment: for some reason bindings stopped working ... this was the solution .. i have no idea why it stopped working in first place

Answer (score 1):

As you said

> course parameter is a ID of a Course

You can use `Request` to get id, try like this

```
public function course_details (Request $request)
{
    return dd($request->course);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue. I think you need to use the 'bindings' middleware on your routes.
See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55949930/2867894

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look on:

```
// Here $course is the id of the Course
public function course_details ($course)
{
    $course =   Course::findOrFail($course);
    return $course;
}
```

But here:

```
// Here $course is the object of the model \App\Course
public function course_details (\App\Course $course)
{
    dd($course);
}
```

that should be

```
public function course_details ($course, \App\Course $_course)
{
    // add your model here with object $_course

    // now $course return the id in your route
    dd($course);
}
```

Comment: Why do I add a ` $_course` parameter? laravel docs says that is enough **_type-hinted variable names match a route segment name And Laravel will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI_** . I do not understand what is $_course and must to add it .

Answer (score 0):

After searching for 2 hours I got the issue details

#### For route binding to work, your type-hinted variable name must match the route placeholder name

For example my edit method

Here is my route URI for the edit

```
user/role/{role}/edit
```

As you can see there is {role} placeholder in the route definition, so the corresponding variable must be called $role.

```
public function edit(Role $role)
{
   return view('role.edit',compact('role'));
}
```