# Laravel not binding model in route

Tags: laravel, routes, binding, laravel-8

When I make a request: `GET /api/users/123/info`, the route does not bind the model, instead it just returns an empty model.

`id: 123` exists in the table. The route is not cached.

Laravel Framework 8.83.27

##### `routes/api/api.php`

```php
Route::get('users/{user}/info', function(User $user) {
    dd(func_get_args());
    // [0 => User{...empty model...}, 1 => 123]
});

Route::get('users/{user}/info', function(User $user, $qwe = 0) {
    dd($qwe, func_get_args());
    // 123, [0 => User{...empty model...}, 1 => 123]
});

Route::get('users/{user}/info', function() {
    dd(func_get_args());
    // [0 => 123]
});
```

Comment: Did you run php artisan route:clear?

Comment: Do you have a `User` record in your database with an `id` of `123`? I forget the requirements (`Route::resource()` vs `Route::get()` maybe?), but sometimes, you get a `ModelNotFoundException`, which translates to an `HTTP 404: Not Found` error, but other times, you get an empty `User` Model. Try navigating to `/users/1/info` (replacing `1` with an `id` of an existing `User`)

Comment: Please show controller code...

Comment: @c4pricorn This code does not use a controller.

Comment: @parastoo yes. This is development mode, I don't use cache.

Comment: @TimLewis I don't use CRUD so Route::resource is not suitable. Data for id:123 exists in table.

Comment: Ok, so try this simple example: `Route::get('/users/{user}/info', function (User $user){ dd($user->toJson()); });`. Then, navigate to `http://localhost:8000/users/123/info`. Does that output your `User` as `JSON`? Locally, that worked for me just fine, even triggering an `HTTP 404` on navigation to something like `/users/bogus/info`.

Comment: @TimLewis have in mind his route has `/api` prefixed, so maybe he has a global middleware messing something or the `RouteServiceProvider` has a different setup than normal `web.php`... Author, please share your `RouteServiceProvider` and what exact URL you are using

Comment: ^ @matiaslauriti Good catch, I was just about to amend my comment saying I tested that in `web.php`; will try in `api.php` and see how it differs. Edit: Moved the route to `api.php` and adjusted navigation to `/api/users/1/info`; same result, so likely something on author's end.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for your answer, but I found a working solution. Updated the thread.

Comment: And I was right, he did mess the basic Kernel config... @AlexanderArhitov why did you add that, instead of having this? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/78ad150a947f6677d9cb4e3eb9a257d312fe14c3/app/Http/Kernel.php#L42-L46

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks, you were indeed right. At the beginning I cut out as much as possible superfluous. And now it's needed. I returned it back, now it works without a group.

Comment: @AlexanderArhitov just have in mind that deviating from the original file is not a good idea, unless you or your team know 100% what they are doing, specially the `kernel.php`. It could definitely be helpful but most of the times changes how the framework works in specific ways and just messes with everyones mind and wastes you time

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69695804/20169439): add in kernel.php

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
             ...
            'bindings' => SubstituteBindings::class,
        ];
```

in group route:

```
Route::middleware(['bindings'])->group(function(){
... you routes here ...
});
```

Update: @matiaslauriti pointed out the configuration error that was causing the problem. The solution above is wrong!

Comment: You must NOT add a `middleware(['bindings'])`, who does not want that to happen? It should already be as a global middleware, or just as the official kernel.php ever had it for `api`... https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/78ad150a947f6677d9cb4e3eb9a257d312fe14c3/app/Http/Kernel.php#L42-L46